# Drag from a collection view cell works on iPad simulator but not on iPhone simulator or real device in Swift 4

Tags: drag-and-drop, swift4

I am using the new drag and drop api in swift 4. I need to drag a cell by long tapping on it and dropping the image on the view controller's view. This is dragging and dropping in the same application because it needs to work on the iPhone, and this feature only works on the phone in the same app. I use a real device for testing what I write and I could not figure out why I cannot drag a cell once I have tapped on it. But running the simulator on iPad and ...it works, I can drag it. I have gone over apple's documentation and they specify that the drag item's appearance can be configured during the drag, but the default is that the whole cell will be dragged if no custom implementation of the delegate's function is present or nil is returned; so it should still work, it does it in the simulator on iPads but not on simulated iPhones or the real one. Code listing below. Maybe someone has gone over this already and knows how to help me. Thank you.
Only the relevant bits:

```
class DefineRoomPropertiesVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Init.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    setupTopMenuBar()
    setupViews()

    topMenuCollectionView.dragDelegate = self
}
   fileprivate let topMenuCollectionView: TopMenuBarCollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = TopMenuBarCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return collectionView
}()
```

}

```
extension DefineRoomPropertiesVC: UICollectionViewDragDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] { // called when a drag is initiated.
    let image = topMenuCollectionView.imagesForTopSectionCell[indexPath.item]
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: image)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    return [dragItem]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
    return nil

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to implement some delegate's methods. Here is the great tutorial: [Coding for iOS 11: How to drag & drop into collections & tables](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313)

Make sure you set *dragInteractionEnabled* flag to *true*

```
collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty stupid, but Apple has enabled the drag interaction for iPad but set it to false on iPhone as a default value.

You would be adding your `UIDragInteraction` to your `UIView`. Make sure that it is enabled by setting the value to true. In my code, it looks as follows.

```
    let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
    dragInteraction.isEnabled = true
    dragView.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
```

Comment: When implementing drag and drop within a `UICollectionView`, should I be adding this inside the `awakeFromNib` method of the cells?